# How to convert from BSON to JSON directly in Python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

I would like to expose MongoDB documents through a JSON HTTP API and I would like to efficiently send those documents from a query to the client. Benchmarking I am seeing that the most time is taken by the serialization process. So I am looking into ways to optimize it. I am using Python (PyMongo, Tastypie).

What I am observing is that PyMongo [decodes BSON into Python dict](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/helpers.py#L115) first, which then I take and encode into JSON. My question is, how could I efficiently convert BSON directly to a string, without the Python dict in between, using a cursor returned by PyMongo as a starting point? Is there a way to hook into the reading process and use some other C library which would decode BSON into JSON? In same way it walks the BSON structure to make a Python dict, it could be already creating a Python string with JSON content.

Is there already such a library? Is there a library in C to convert BSON to JSON directly?

Comment: Not quite. BSON is not compatible with JSON, because it has dates and binary fields. But it's a minor issue. As for the question: I don't think there is such library, you would have to write one on your own. But the question is: if you need it then perhaps you are doing something wrong? Why would you need this kind of optimization? If the serialization process takes most time then it's good, because it is still is fast enough for most cases. Or perhaps Python is a wrong language in the first place?

Comment: Python is so that it handles the rest of the API (authentication, throttling, permissions), but yes, for reading the data itself is less suitable. But there are ways to use C libraries in it, but I am afraid that I would have to write it myself.